# Decimal to binary (and vice-versa)

Tags: c++, binary, decimal

Can anybody give an example of c++ code that can easily convert a decimal value to binary and a binary value to decimal please?

Comment: In what format? Strings? Numerical types don't care about base, since they're all stored as binary data regardless...

Comment: Where'd the `"guru"` part in the name come from? ;-)

Comment: it can be anything int...String...i was looking for smallest and efficient code.

Comment: Likely duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819487/efficiently-convert-between-hex-binary-and-decimal-in-c-c

Comment: The question doesn't make sense if it's an `int`, Codeguru.

Comment: @Dav: I'm guessing Codeguru actually means that the input could be anything, but the output should be a string?

Comment: @mjv: +1.  My handle used to be UfcChampion9YearsRunning...

Comment: @MaxGuernseyIII: LOL.  Assuming UFC is as in "Ultimate Fighting", at least nobody would dare make fun of your handle...  I couldn't resist here with our OP, a guru who doesn't find his way around google or a good reference book ;-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, your question is really vague, so this answer is the same.

```
string DecToBin(int number)
{
    if ( number == 0 ) return "0";
    if ( number == 1 ) return "1";

    if ( number % 2 == 0 )
        return DecToBin(number / 2) + "0";
    else
        return DecToBin(number / 2) + "1";
}

int BinToDec(string number)
{
    int result = 0, pow = 1;
    for ( int i = number.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i, pow <<= 1 )
        result += (number[i] - '0') * pow;

    return result;
}
```

You should check for overflow and do input validation of course.

`x << 1 == x * 2`

Here's a way to convert to binary that uses a more "programming-like" approach rather than a "math-like" approach, for lack of a better description (the two are actually identical though, since this one just replaces divisions by right shifts, modulo by a bitwise and, recursion with a loop. It's kind of another way of thinking about it though, since this makes it obvious you are extracting the individual bits).

```
string DecToBin2(int number)
{
    string result = "";

    do
    {
        if ( (number & 1) == 0 )
            result += "0";
        else
            result += "1";

        number >>= 1;
    } while ( number );

    reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}
```

And here is how to do the conversion on paper:

1. [Decimal to binary](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary)
2. [Binary to decimal](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Binary-to-Decimal)

Comment: What if we want to have a fixed length of binary number? For example, if we would like to have an 8 bit representation, then `1` has to be returned as `00000001`.

Comment: @Rasoul - then just add leading zeros until you get your desired length. Some programming languages provide methods to do this out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

`strtol` will convert a binary string like "011101" to an internal value (which will normally be stored in binary as well, but you don't need to worry much about that). A normal conversion (e.g. `operator<<` with `std:cout`) will give the same value in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

```
//The shortest solution to convert dec to bin in c++

void dec2bin(int a) {
    if(a!=0) dec2bin(a/2);
    if(a!=0) cout<<a%2;
}
int main() {
    int a;
    cout<<"Enter the number: "<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    dec2bin(a);
    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want a string to binary conversion?

```
template<typename T> T stringTo( const std::string& s )
   {
      std::istringstream iss(s);
      T x;
      iss >> x;
      return x;
   };

template<typename T> inline std::string toString( const T& x )
   {
      std::ostringstream o;
      o << x;
      return o.str();
   }
```

use these like this:

```
int x = 32;
std:string decimal = toString<int>(x);
int y = stringTo<int>(decimal);
```