# Can anyone help me understand the execution of this code?

Tags: c

I am a beginner in programming and I am trying to understand a code that converts decimal to binary.  The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  long int DN,quo;
  int rem[106],i=1,j;

  printf("give me a decimal number: ");
  scanf("%ld", &DN);

  quo = DN;

  while(quo!=0)
  {
     rem[i]= quo % 2;
     quo = quo / 2;
     i++;
  }

  printf("Equivalent binary value of your decimal number %ld\n: ",DN);

  for(j = i-1 ;j> 0;j--)
     printf("%d",rem[j]);
}
```

Can anyone help me understand the part beginning with the while loop? I am very sorry for posting such a simple question.

Comment: So how is the for loop at the bottom making sure that I get my remainders in reverse order?

Comment: Its a code to convert decimal number to binary. further reading  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86207/converting-decimalbase-10-numbers-to-binary-by-repeatedly-dividing-by-2   and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548282/decimal-to-binary-and-vice-versa

Comment: Please use a debug executable and with the help of any debugger like gdb you can very well understand yourself what values are getting stored in `rem[]` and what is the value of `i` just before the `for` loop. It will improve your understanding of the code.

Comment: @yellowantphil that is what I am confused about. I can acknowledge the fact that I am not so logically driven. So the initialization value is j = i -1, since I start with i = 1 in my code above, and let's say I want to find the binary conversion of 8, my rem [1] = 0, rem [2] = 0, rem [3] = 0 and rem [4] = 1. Now coming to the for loop, since I start with j = i - 1 and then decrease until j > 0, does it mean I take i = 3 first? I hope I do not sound too confusing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose input decimal number is 13

```
Step 1. 13/2 , Remainder = 1, Quotient = 6
Step 2. 6/2 , Remainder = 0, Quotient = 3
Step 3. 3/2 , Remainder = 1, Quotient = 1
Step 4. 1/2 , Remainder = 1, Quotient = 0
```

Now, the Binary equivalent of 13 is the remainders in reverse order : 1101

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation of the standard way to convert a number to its decimal representation.

1. [quotioent, remainder] = a ÷ 2
2. d[i] = remainder
3. If quotient is 0 we're done
4. else goto 1
5. Read d[i] backwards and print it out.