# How would I convert decimal into binary?

Tags: c++, binary, decimal

All I really know is PHP and I used the `decbin` function etc, It was fairly easy to do. In this C++ program I want to do the same thing, just a simple number or string how would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple function could be defined such as this:

```
void binary(int decimal) {
   int remainder;

   if(decimal <= 1) {
       std::cout << decimal;
       return;
   }
   remainder = decimal % 2;
   binary(decimal >> 1);    
   std::cout << remainder;
}
```

Although there are many other resources on the web on how to do this..

A noteworthy question for efficiency of it here, as you may want more than just that: 
[Efficiently convert between Hex, Binary, and Decimal in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819487/efficiently-convert-between-hex-binary-and-decimal-in-c-c)

Comment: @oni-kun, C++ has a lot more to offer if you look into it, decbin isn't all that different from these solutions.

Comment: The parameter name `int decimal` makes no sense. Numbers aren't inherently decimal, they are just numbers. (In fact, they are always stored in binary form internally.)

Comment: @Fred, It is decimal into binary, hence the param. He didn't specify any other data type.

Comment: @Null But `int` is NOT a decimal type! It just so happens that the common output routines will print an `int` as a decimal number. The calls `binary(37)` and `binary(0x25)` are completely equivalent -- the arguments are neither decimal nor hexadecimal, they are just integral numbers -- `int`s.

Comment: @Fred the integer represents a decimal, I can make it a float or double for all it matters, the name of the `int` was decimal as that was the suggested input.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this non-recursively using something like this:

```
std::string Dec2Bin(int nValue, bool bReverse = false)
{
    std::string sBin;  
    while(nValue != 0)
    {
       sBin += (nValue & 1) ? '1' : '0';
       nValue >>= 1;
    }

    if(!bReverse)        
        std::reverse(sBin.begin(),sBin.end());

    return sBin;
}
```

of course this isn't *too* architucture friendly, but it avoids cout, just incase your not using a console. it also outputs in any bit ordering.

Comment: Maybe add replace last line with something like `return sBin.size() ? sBin : "0"`, so as to display `0` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itoa`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) if it's available on your compiler. Just remember **it's not standard** and if you need a standard method you're better off using the other solutions posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print it, just use this code [here](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/expressions/2binbybitops.html).  If you want to return a string, instead of using `cout`, append to a C++ string instead.

Answer (score 0):

offering the iterative approach (pardon the #defines (but i'm quite sure they will be compiled to the expression's value), i don't quite remember predefined macro/constants in C):

```
#define INT_ARCH 32
#define ARCH_SHIFTABLE (INT_ARCH - 1)
#define ARCH_MAX_INT 1 << ARCH_SHIFTABLE

void dec_to_bin(int decimal)
{                
    int shifter = ARCH_MAX_INT;

    for(; shifter > 0; shifter >>= 1)
        cout << (decimal & shifter);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Necrolis answer without the need for an if, and the reversal of the string.

```
string decimalToBinary(int decimal) {
  string binary;
  while(decimal)  {
      binary.insert(0, 1, (decimal & 1) + '0');
      decimal >>= 1;
  }
  return binary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do with simple way in c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
long n, rem, binary=0, i=1;
cout<<"Enter a int: ";
cin>>n;

 while(n != 0) 
   {
        rem = n%2;      
        n = n/2;        
        binary= binary + (rem*i); 
        i = i*10;
    }
cout<< "\nAns:   "<<binary <<endl;

return 0;
}
```