# C++ base conversion

Tags: c++, radix

Hello I'm trying to port some code from Windows to Linux. I have this:

```
itoa(word,aux,2);
```

But GCC doesn't recognize itoa. How can I do this conversion to base 2 on a C++ way?

Thanks ;)

Comment: no, gcc does not recognize itoa.

You could start by naming the types of word,aux,2

Comment: See [How would I convert decimal into binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801859/how-would-i-convert-decimal-into-binary).  It's specifically about formatting an integer as a binary string in C++.  Necrolis's solution actually returns a string (rather than printing to cout).

Answer (score 2):

[Here´](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itoa)s some help

```
/* itoa:  convert n to characters in s */
 void itoa(int n, char s[])
 {
     int i, sign;

     if ((sign = n) < 0)  /* record sign */
         n = -n;          /* make n positive */
     i = 0;
     do {       /* generate digits in reverse order */
         s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';   /* get next digit */
     } while ((n /= 10) > 0);     /* delete it */
     if (sign < 0)
         s[i++] = '-';
     s[i] = '\0';
     reverse(s);
 }
```

You should adapt it to your needs (notice this one has 2 arguments, not 3)
Also notice the reverse function is also in the wikipedia link.

Additionally, [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) are some other cases (but not for base 2)

> This function is not defined in ANSI-C
>   and is not part of C++, but is
>   supported by some compilers.
>
> A standard-compliant alternative for
>   some cases may be sprintf:

`sprintf(str,"%d",value)` converts to decimal base.

`sprintf(str,"%x",value)`  converts to hexadecimal base.

`sprintf(str,"%o",value)` converts to octal base.

Answer (score 2):

Here is Tom's answer, modified to use the base as your code requires:

```
void itoa(int n, char s[], std::size_t base = 10) {
    const char digits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    int i, sign;

    if (base < 2 || base > 16)
        throw std::invalid_argument("invalid base");
    if ((sign = n) < 0)  /* record sign */
        n = -n;      /* make n positive */
    i = 0;
    do {       /* generate digits in reverse order */
        s[i++] = digits[n % base]; /* get next digit */
    } while ((n /= base) > 0);         /* delete it */
    if (sign < 0)
        s[i++] = '-';
    s[i] = '\0';
    reverse(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a page of itoa implementations [here](http://www.jb.man.ac.uk/~slowe/cpp/itoa.html)

Answer (score 1):

what about boost::lexical_cast ???

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm

Comment: I love this tool, although be warned that [it isn't the fastest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1251051/1830736).

Comment: I don't know what was in the past, but now it's faster than about everything, look at this performance comparison table :)
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html

Answer (score 0):

What about using the power of recursion? :)

```
int convert_base(int v, int b){ 

    if (v == 0) return 0;   
    else 
        return (v%b+10*convert_base(v/b,b));    
}
```